# print json_encode of a MySQL SUM() function

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, json

I am trying to print with JSON a SUM() of a price.

Currently I am trying:

```
$query="SELECT SUM(cost) FROM `Service`";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$json = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
            $json['cost'] = $row['cost'];
    }
    print json_encode($json);
mysql_close();
```

This returns null.

If I try `SELECT cost FROM Service` instead, it returns the last cost from the database.

What Im I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

supply an `ALIAS` on the column passed on the aggregate function

```
SELECT SUM(cost) totalCOST FROM `Service`
```

so you can fetch the columnName

```
$json['cost'] = $row['totalCOST'];
```